# Jquery plugin - toolbar.js > link not work

Tags: javascript, jquery, hyperlink, toolbarjs

I have this code, where there are 3 links, but when I click on link, on footer bar of firefox, show the link, but do not open the link. If click on the mouse roll, open the page. The sx button of mouse work fine on other sites or windows function.

```
<head>
<link href="tooltip/documentation.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="tooltip/jquery.toolbars.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lustria" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<!--[if gte IE 9]>
<style type="text/css">
            .gradient {
               filter: none !important;
            }

            .tool-container.tool-top {
                border-bottom: none;
            }

          </style>
<![endif]-->
<link href="tooltip/bootstrap.icons.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="tooltip/prettify.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="tooltip/sunburst.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="tooltip/prettify.js"></script>
<script src="tooltip/jquery.toolbar.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
            jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

                // Define any icon actions before calling the toolbar
                $('.toolbar-icons a').on('click', function( event ) {
                    event.preventDefault();
                });
                 $('.settings-button').toolbar({content: '#user-options', position: 'bottom'});
                $('#normal-button').toolbar({content: '#user-options', position: 'top'});
                $('.normal-button-bottom').toolbar({content: '#user-options', position: 'bottom'});
                $('.normal-button-small').toolbar({content: '#user-options-small', position: 'top', hideOnClick: true});
                $('#button-left').toolbar({content: '#user-options', position: 'left'});
                $('#button-right').toolbar({content: '#user-options', position: 'right'});
                $('#link-toolbar').toolbar({content: '#user-options', position: 'top' });
            });
        </script>
</head>

</head>

<body onload="prettyPrint()">


<div id="normal-button-bottom" class="settings-button"> <img src="tooltip/icon-cog-small.png" /> </div>
<br><br>
<div id="normal-button-bottom" class="settings-button"> <img src="tooltip/icon-cog-small.png" /> </div>


<div id="user-options-small" class="toolbar-icons" style="display: none;">  
    <a href>
        <i class="icon-align-left"></i>
    </a>
    <a href>    
        <i class="icon-align-center"></i>
    </a>
    <a href>
        <i class="icon-align-right"></i>
    </a>
</div>
<div id="user-options" class="toolbar-icons" style="display: none;">
    <a href="http://google.it">
        <i class="icon-user"></i>
    </a>
    <a href="http://yahoo.it">
        <i class="icon-star"></i>
    </a>
    <a href="http://www.tiscali.it">
        <i class="icon-edit"></i>
    </a>
    <a href="#">
        <i class="icon-trash"></i>
    </a>
    <a href="#">
        <i class="icon-ban-circle"></i>
    </a>
</div>
</body>

</html>
```

How to links work?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
    // Define any icon actions before calling the toolbar
    $('.toolbar-icons a').on('click', function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();
    });
    $('.settings-button').toolbar({
        content: '#user-options',
        position: 'bottom',
    });
    $('.settings-button').on('toolbarItemClick', function (e, el) {
        if (el.href) window.location.href = el.href;
    });
});
```

use that instead